# Guava Multimap containsEntry issues

Tags: java, collections, guava, multimap

Below I have some code that adds two entries to the first multimap and a single entry to the second, then compares the two. Since the keys are the same "Dec" (see output), why does it output false?

input

```
    Multimap<String, String> first = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    Multimap<String, String> second = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    first.put("Dec", "18");
    first.put("Dec", "12");
    second.put("Dec", "18");
    for (String key : second.keys()) {
            System.out.println(first.get(key));
        System.out.println(second.get(key));
        System.out.println(first.containsEntry(key, second.get(key)));
    }
```

output

```
    [18, 12]
    [18]
    false
```

Edit: For those who don't understand the answer below, second.get(key) will return a collection of strings (albeit only one) and of course a collection of strings =/= string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for an entry with a key of `"Dec"` and a value of "a collection containing just `"18"`". That entry *doesn't* exist in either `first` or `second`.

Now if you use:

```
System.out.println(first.containsEntry("Dec", "18"));
```

then I expect that *will* print `true`. Basically you need to distinguish between an individual entry value and "the collection of entry values associated with a key".

Comment: There's no such method as `Iterables.first`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman,     second.get(key).iterator().next() has the same idea.

Comment: Indeed.  (I was mostly just trying to explain to Jon why I'd edited his answer to be more precise.)